# iterate through all rows/columns openpyxl not working anymore with new version >2.3.5

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pydev, openpyxl

with the version 2.3.5 of openpyxl this code works:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

excel_file = load_workbook(excel_file_path,read_only=True)

sheet = excel_file["Sheet1"]

    mylist = []
    for row in sheet:
        for cell in row:
            mylist.append((cell.value, cell.row, cell.column))
```

i did this so i can process my large excel file faster. but with the new version since 2.4.x this doesnt work anymore, the first "for-loop" breaks immediately, what has changed in the version ? or how can i do the same with the latest version of openpyxl ?

Comment: What do you mean "breaks"? Please provide a full traceback.

Comment: i mean it doesnt even executes the first loop it just jumps at the next line of code the first "for-loop" is not even entered

Comment: This happens with the new version any time I set `read_only` to `True`. Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: Well, it could be a poor file. Can't really say without seeing it but the code hasn't changed here.

Comment: @CharlieClark, I have tested this on over 5 excel files just now. It behaves the same way (works when `read_only = False`, but does not when `read_only = True`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be happening only when you have the `read_only` parameter set to `True` when loading your workbook.
My workaround has been to use the `max_row` attribute of the `sheet` to create a `range` of values to loop through as row indices:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

excel_file = load_workbook(excel_file_path,read_only=True)
sheet = excel_file["Sheet1"]

mylist = []
row_num = sheet.max_row

for row_index in range(1,row_num):
    for cell in sheet[row_index]:
        mylist.append((cell.value, cell.row, cell.column))
```

Hopefully @CharlieClark can shed some light on this. But in the meantime, I hope this is helpful.

Comment: thanks ive tried it this is indeed a workaround that works with the new version, still it would be nice to know what has changed and why is the code above not working with the latest version